Is there a way to resolve the ‘client’ and ‘developement’ tags ambiguities?
client (26 occurrences) has currently several uses related to:

(~15) the main bitcoin client
(~9) a (possibly alternative) bitcoin client
(~2) a generic client (networking term) for various web and misc. APIs

development (15 occurrences) has also several uses:

(~6) the core bitcoin development
(~2) alternative bitcoin client development
(~5) web and misc. bitcoin programming
(~3) related to building the client from source. (wrongly tagged maybe).

Which of those uses should be distinguished, and how?

I certainly think that we should split up the client tag to distinguish between Satoshi's original client and other clients. I don't think that we need to split the development tag then since you could use the development tag + one of the client tags.
Not sure what to call the tags though.

For Satoshi's client: main-client? original-client?
Fot other clients: client? alternative-client?


plural “clients” might be considered for other clients maybe.
